# How to reboot WAG54G2 from Web Management

Tags: router, reboot

How can I reboot my Linksys WAG54G2 router from the web management interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're out of luck, no restart from the HTML interface of the WAG54G2.

power off/on is the only way.

*... what were they thinking?*

Comment: So is there any other way? like connecting though telnet or hyper terminal or something else!!?
How did they forget to do this!!!!

Comment: no, there is no other way. this model is not supported by any 3rd party firmware either, the only hope is a decent firmware upgrade by Linksys.

Answer (score 8):

You can do the backup/restore trick:

1. Go to the Backup & Restore page under Administration:

   [image: Router screenshot]
2. Backup your configuration.
3. Restore with the backup you just saved.

This makes your router restart but changes nothing in the configuration!

Answer (score 0):

Open your web browser and enter this address:

```
http://your.router.ip/setup.cgi?todo=reboot
```

E.g. if your router IP is `192.168.1.1` then enter the following:

```
http://192.168.1.1/setup.cgi?todo=reboot
```

Comment: I've tried before and was not working!!! I think this hack is related to certain firmware version!! I have the latest and not working on it

Comment: He did say "from the web interface."

Comment: Tried and doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I use this web form for remote reboot: `http://192.168.1.1/Reset.htm`

Comment: Superficially this looks the same as the answer from 2011. What makes this one different?

Comment: @JonathanGarber, the URL. None of the other answers link to this specific page, which if correct for the router in question, would make it a good answer.

Comment: @Synetech: Indeed. Hence the "superficially" bit. You're right that I should have been more explicit. Alex, if you could edit the answer to explain how it's different and what it does, it would be a better answer than it is now. That's what we're all about here at Stack Exchange: The best possible answers to questions.

Comment: @JonathanGarber, it’s different because it’s a different URL. Obviously. What it does is to reset the router. Obviously. The only thing that Alex can add is whether they in fact are using the same router make and model as AMgdy.

Comment: @JonathanGarber

Comment: Sorry I'm newbie...
@JonathanGarber: All of URL described in answers before mine doesn't work. That's why I thought that my answer could help person who struggling like me. Regarding model of router: It’s same as in original question.

Comment: Respect, Alex. Very few people are able to resist the stupid crowd in our days. The cattle is even unable to see that `reset.htm` is shorter than `setup.cgi?next_file=reboot_guage.htm`! I would give you more than +1 for good answer and commitment to the truth, if I could.

Answer (score -1):

This syntax works for WAG54G2 V1.00.19:

http://your.router.ip/setup.cgi?next_file=reboot_guage.htm

e.g. if your router ip is 192.168.1.1 then:

http://192.168.1.1/setup.cgi?next_file=reboot_guage.htm

Comment: It's just showing the reboot progress screen but not actually reboot the device

Comment: @Robert do you have the reboot URL's for other routers as well? I'm trying to put together a list to write software ppl can use to reboot remotely or without having to go downstairs to their routers, UPnP/HNAP etc are all hit and miss/useless... so if you have more reboot URL's for other versions or routers, we will finally be able to solve this problem once and for all! Would love your help. Contact me.